# Proving De Morgan's Generalized Laws

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How can I prove the generalized De Morgan laws using mathematical writing, and not induction (I am not allowed).

This is what I concluded:

$\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i' = (\bigcup_{i\in I}(A_i)).$
and its opposite:

$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i' = (\bigcap_{i\in I}(A_i)).$

I know how to prove it using induction, but I am not allowed unfortunately. I am requested to prove only using logic (mathematical writing).

This is how I've generalized it: $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i  iff \exists \:i\left(i\in \:I\:\:∧\:x\in \:A_{_{_i}}\right)$

and the other one: $(\bigcap_{i\in I}(A_i)) iff \forall i(i\in I\:->\:X\in A_i)$

but I don't know how to prove it using logic for the generalized form.

Please show me how to do it correctly, I've written what I've already done.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

\begin{align}x\in \bigcap_{i\in I}A_i'&\iff x\in A_i',\forall i\in I \\ &\iff x\notin A_i,\forall i\in I\\&\iff x\notin \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\\&\iff x\in \left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\right)' \end{align}

which shows $$\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i=\left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\right)'.$$ Proceed in the same way to get the other equality.